# Java DataInputStream usage with System.in

Tags: java, datainputstream

A simple programm

```
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    while(true)
        System.out.println(in.readUTF());
```

Behaves somewhat weird: it refuses to output the inputed text... I use terminal to input some text into it, but there's nothing in the output. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not weird at all. `readUTF` expects a *very specific* length-prefixed format as written by `DataOutputStream`. That's not what your terminal will be providing. See the documentation in [`DataInput.readUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) for more details.

You should generally just use a `Scanner` or create an `InputStreamReader` around `System.in`, and a `BufferedReader` around that, and use `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Answer (score 2):

DataInputStream is for reading binary data.  readUTF expects a two byte unsigned length followed by the characters in UTF-8. (If you are intreested you can read it's documentation hint, hint)

I suspect what you intended to use was Scanner which is designed to read text.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(in.hasNextLine())
    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like

```
String str;
while((str = in.readUTF()) != null) {
     System.out.println(str);
}
```